# intento enviar un formulario desde VSC a Php y me aparece este error

Tags: php, visual-studio, xampp

Me aparece este error cuando intento enviar un formulario desde VSC a php por multiplataforma Xammp no he logrado solucionarlo.

> Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '98437589348', 'oahsdfi')' at line 2 in C:\Users\molan\OneDrive\Escritorio\Xammp1.0\htdocs\Proyecto-sena\send.php:26 Stack trace: #0 C:\Users\molan\OneDrive\Escritorio\Xammp1.0\htdocs\Proyecto-sena\send.php(26): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'INSERT INTO dat...') #1 C:\Users\molan\OneDrive\Escritorio\Xammp1.0\htdocs\Proyecto-sena\index.php(56): include('C:\Users\molan\...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\Users\molan\OneDrive\Escritorio\Xammp1.0\htdocs\Proyecto-sena\send.php on line 26

Comment: Te dice que tienes un error en la instruccion de insert. Por favor agrega el código de tu php para insertar datos y un ejemplo de sql de como insertas en la tabla .

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: que es VSC ??? como envias un formulario desde VSC a php??? y que es por multiplataforma xampp??? tu pregunta es confusa y a pesar de que conosco los termino, no logro entender lo que argumentas...

Comment: te recomiendo hacer el [tour]